# Mysql cast to decimal give 99.9

Tags: mysql, casting

I got a varchar field say the value as 174 but when I `cast(field as decimal(3,1))` it gives me always 99.9? How can I cast or convert it to be 17.4? Or must I change at source level the input to be input in decimal itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `174` cannot be expressed with 2 digits before and 1 digit after the decimal point. `decimal(3,1)` means "3 digits in total and 1 (of the 3) after the decimal point.

```
mysql> select cast('174' as decimal(3,1));
+-----------------------------+
| cast('174' as decimal(3,1)) |
+-----------------------------+
|                        99.9 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

It gives a warning that can be shown with:

```
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                              |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'cast('174' as decimal(3,1))' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Divide the number by 10 and try again:

```
mysql> select cast('174'/10 as decimal(3,1));
+--------------------------------+
| cast('174'/10 as decimal(3,1)) |
+--------------------------------+
|                           17.4 |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: so if I have my field as integer I can do the same divide my 10 then cast is that correct?

Comment: Yes. The `'174'/10` implicitly casts the varchar to an int.

Comment: No what I meant if the field is integer for e.g. 174 then divide by 10 is the same answer right?

Comment: Yes. Exaclty the same. `select cast(174/10 as decimal(3,1));` gives `17.4`. You only have to make sure that the result of 174/10 actually _fits_ into `decimal(3,1)`.